# Machine learning for finding even/odd number getting incorrect/correct output for two different classifiers

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, classification, scikit-learn

I tried a Machine Learning algorithm on a hypothetical problem :-

I made a fake feature vector and a fake result data set by the following python code :-

```
x=[]
y=[]
for i in range(0,100000):
    mylist=[]
    mylist.append(i)
    mylist.append(i)
    x.append(mylist)
    if(i%2)==0:
        y.append(0)
    else:
        y.append(1)
```

The above code gives me 2 python lists, namely, 
x = [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]....and so on] #this list contains the fake feature vector, with 2 same numbers

y = [0,1,0..... and so on] #this has the fake test labels, 0 for even, 1 for odd

I think the test data is good enough for a ML algorithm to learn. I use the following python code to train a couple of different machine learning models.

Approach 1 : Gaussian Naive Bayes

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(x,y)
x_pred = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[10,10],[11,11],[12,12],[13,13],[14,14],[15,15],[16,16]]
y_pred=gnb.predict(x_pred)
print y_pred
```

I get the following incorrect output, the classifier fails to predict :-

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Approach 2 : Support Vector Machines

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(x, y)
x_pred = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[10,10],[11,11],[12,12],[13,13],[14,14],[15,15],[16,16]]
y_pred=clf.predict(x_pred)
print y_pred
```

I get the following correct output, the classifier fails to predict :-

```
[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
```

Can someone put light on this and explain why one approach had 50% accuracy and the other one had 100% accuracy.

Let me know if this question is tagged with a wrong category.

Comment: Similar question in stats: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161189/train-a-neural-network-to-distinguish-between-even-and-odd-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naive Bayes is a parametric model: it tries to summarize your training set in nine parameters, the class prior (50% for either class) and the per-class, per-feature means and variances. However, your target value `y` is not a function of the means and variances of the inputs `x` in any way,(*) so the parameters are irrelevant and the model resorts to what is effectively random guessing.

By contrast, the support vector machine remembers its training set and compares new inputs to its training inputs using a kernel function. It's supposed to pick a subset of its training samples, but for this problem it's forced to just remember all of them:

```
>>> x = np.vstack([np.arange(100), np.arange(100)]).T
>>> y = x[:, 0] % 2
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> clf.fit(x, y)
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
>>> clf.support_vectors_.shape
(100, 2)
```

Since you're using test samples that occurred in the training set, all it has to do is look up the label that the samples you presented had in the training set and return those, so you get 100% accuracy. If you feed the SVM samples outside of the training set, you'll see that it too starts guessing randomly:

```
>>> clf.predict(x * 2)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Since multiplying by two makes all the features even, the true labeling would have been all zero and the accuracy is 50%: the accuracy of a random guess.

(*) Actually there is some dependence in the training set, but that drops off with more data.

Comment: I have a naive question, then what amount of data and what classifier can be used in such a problem where we need to predict if a number is even or odd ? Or this is not a machine learning problem altogether ? Let us say that there is no way to find even/odd numbers i.e. mod operator of all sorts is gone and there is no other  way. Then how do we go about this problem. I might sound crazy but this is just a random thought.

Comment: @divyenduz You can use `k % 2` to find out if `k` is even, so no, I wouldn't use machine learning to solve this problem. You can devise features to make pretty much any classification learner learn this, but they'll be either trivial or contrived.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I will wait for a few hours before closing this question. Someone might come up with something. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mark it as complete earlier. Done today, thanks.